# php send email with attachment

Tags: php, email-attachments

I have this script that works fine only with Fullname and the attachment file. However if I add one more field for example "tel", the script will send except the attachment. Can some one help me please?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        //The form has been submitted, prep a nice thank you fullname
        $output = '<h1>Thanks for your file and fullname!</h1>';
        //Set the form flag to no display (cheap way!)
        $flags = 'style="display:none;"';

        //Deal with the email
        $to = 'email here';
        $subject = 'a file for you';

        $fullname = strip_tags($_POST['fullname']);
        $tel = strip_tags($_POST['tel']);

        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

        $boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 

        $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
        $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";

        $fullname="This is a multi-part fullname in MIME format.

--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

--_2_$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$fullname

--_2_$boundary--
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

$attachment
--_1_$boundary--";



        mail($to, $subject, $fullname, $headers);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>MailFile</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php echo $output; ?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" <?php echo $flags;?>>
<p><label for="fullname">Full name</label> <input name="fullname" id="fullname" /></p>
<p><label for="file">File</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file"></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="send"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't seem to do anything with `$tel`... :-? You define it and then ignore it.

Answer (score 16):

There is no need to re-invent the wheel. Use the [phpmailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/source/browse/trunk/class.phpmailer.php) class and then you can add attachments as simple as

```
function emailWithAttachment($to, $subject, $message, $attachment) {

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->AddAddress($to);

    $mail->From         = "your@email.com";
    $mail->FromName     = "Your Name";
    $mail->Subject      = $subject;
    $mail->Body         = $message;

    $mail->AddAttachment($attachment);

}
```

Here is your script, rewritten using phpmailer.class

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        //The form has been submitted, prep a nice thank you fullname
        $output = '<h1>Thanks for your file and fullname!</h1>';

        //Set the form flag to no display (cheap way!)
        $flags = 'style="display:none;"';

        // include and start phpmailer
        require_once('PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        //Deal with the email
        $mail->From = "webmaster@example.com"; // from
        $mail->AddReplyTo("webmaster@example.com", "Webmaster"); // reply to address/name

        $mail->AddAddress('email@address.here'); // to address

        $mail->Subject = 'A file for you'; // subject

        $mail->Body = $fullname; // body

        $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); // attach uploaded file
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>MailFile</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php echo $output; ?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" <?php echo $flags;?>>
<p><label for="fullname">Full name</label> <input name="fullname" id="fullname" /></p>
<p><label for="file">File</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file"></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="send"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you are right. But its complicated for me... I cannot understand how to configure it. My example is working, I only need to add onemore filed!

Comment: I updated my answer to rewrite your script using phpmailer. It's much shorter and simpler in my opinion, but understand if it's not the direction you want to take.

Comment: Better to add the file name as well to get attachment with filename and type :) `$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['file']['name']);`

Comment: It gives this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting ',' or ';' in D:\xampp\htdocs\site\php-mailer.class.php on line 134`

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php 
//define the receiver of the email   
$to = 'youraddress@example.com'; 
//define the subject of the email 
$subject = 'Test email with attachment'; 
//create a boundary string. It must be unique 
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash 
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n 
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com"; 
//add boundary string and mime type specification 
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 
//read the atachment file contents into a string,
//encode it with MIME base64,
//and split it into smaller chunks
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('attachment.zip'))); 
//define the body of the message. 
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
```

?> 
    --PHP-mixed-
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-"

```
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!! 
This is simple text email message. 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2> 
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p> 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.zip"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment  

<?php echo $attachment; ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

<?php 
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer 
$message = ob_get_clean(); 
//send the email 
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed"; 
?>
```