# phpmailer with attachment is not working in cron job

Tags: php, linux, cron, phpmailer

i am able to send mail but not with attachment using cron job i,e i can able to send mail but not with attachment using cronjob... please i need a help right now.. i am struck in this for past 2 days.

code:

```
<?php

    dirname(__FILE__);
    $data;
    $data1;
    $d1="localhost";
    $d2="username";
    $d3="password";
    mysql_connect($d1,$d2,$d3);
    $d4="database name";
    mysql_select_db($d4) or die("cannot connect db");
    $sql = "select * from members";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die("cannot select db");
    $count = mysql_num_fields($res);

    // fetch table header from database
    $header = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
        $header .= mysql_field_name($res, $i);
    }

    // fetch data each row, store on tabular row data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)){
        $line = "";
        foreach($row as $value){
            if(!isset($value) || $value == ""){
                $value = "\t";
            }else{
                $value = str_replace("", "", $value);
                $value = "" . $value . "" ;
            }
            $line .= $value;
        }
        $data1 .= trim($line)."\n";
        $data = str_replace("\r", "", $data1);
    }

    $name=date("d-m-y")."-list.xls";
    $ran=rand(1,1000);
    $d5="exportfile";
    $ourFileName =$d5;
    $d6=".xls";
    $et=$d6;

    if(file_exists($ourFileName.$et))
        file_put_contents($ourFileName.$ran.$et, $header."\n".$data);

    $file=$ourFileName.$ran.$et;
    require("class.phpmailer.php");
    require("class.smtp.php");
    require("/home/freetech/public_html/akw/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $us="username";    
    $pswd="password";
    $hst="server link";
    $frm="akw@hostname.com";                           // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = $us;                            // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = $pswd; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Host     = $hst; // SMTP server
    $mail->Port     =465;
    $mail->From     = $frm;

    $mail->AddAddress("email address");

    $mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
    $mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail.";
    $mail->AddAttachment("/home/freetech/public_html/akw/".$file);      // attachment
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->Send();
?>
```

Comment: Is attachment located at proper position? Does it have read permission?
This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064619/php-send-email-with-attachment

Comment: yes, i gave every permission & the attachment is in the proper position too but that doesn't ring a bell!!

Comment: Welcome to the site! You have a tremendous amount of dead code and meaningless variable names here, so it is hard to analyze your problem. For example, the first three lines don't do anything at all. I would suggest you go read some basic tutorials and give your variables meaningful names, then come back.

Comment: @user3304531, by which user cron job is running??

Comment: yes the attachment is given permission of 755...the major problem is im not able to send any mail using phpmailer while scheduling with cronjob ...but when i send it using browser method ..the script is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Like Ravi said, Since the file is in the freetech user's directory the cronjob should set by/belong to the freetech user. What is the permission on this directory? /home/freetech/public_html/akw/

Comment: Hey, why don't you try placing your file to `/tmp` ??

Comment: the permission is 755 for all folders and files

Comment: Who is the owner of /home/freetech/public_html/akw/
it might be apache.

Comment: so what if the owner is apache?? dont get u.. and i have tried in tmp its still not working

Comment: The attachment is created by apache and sent by apache when using this via the browser.  The cronjob doesn't seem to be apache.  So its not allowed to send off apache's file.  Who is the owner of the cronjob?

Comment: oh..thanks for info....but how to know who is owner of cronjob?..and also i tried using normal php mail script which is working fine..

Comment: If you are root try this on the command line:

for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do crontab -u $user -l; done

Comment: no...not able to execute ur command arikin ..think bcoz it doesnot have command line option..

Comment: Moved this to my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cronjob and the apache user may be different.  Therefore they can't send each other's files or use their classes.

If the file being attached needs to be sent by either apache and a cronjob make sure the cronjob is for a user that has permission to use the file or class.

Check to see the owner and permission of the directory you are using to save the attachment file in.  Also, check these of any required classes.

```
ll -a /home/freetech/public_html/
```

What is listed for the akw directory?

Then check to see which user is running the cronjob. On the command line try this as root:

```
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do crontab -u $user -l; done
```

If not root then try one user at a time:

```
crontab -u apache -l
crontab -u freetech -l
```

If the cronjob is in freetech then find which group you are in:

```
groups freetech
id -Gn freetech
```

Then change the group on that akw directory to match:

```
cd /home/freetech/public_html/
chown apache:freetech akw
chmod 774 akw
```

As for making your code look nice... An example of sending attachments with phpmailer:

[Example 1](http://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/a-simple-example-sending-email-with-attachment-using-phpmailer/) / [Example 2](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/AdvancedMail)

Comment: thank you so much for answer...but my problem is not only with attCHMENTS..but also with normal mail without attachments using phpmailer.as mentioned before same problem arises when a mail is sent using phpmailer with a cron job...sample code for normal mail

Comment: I will assume class.phpmailer.php and class.smtp.php are in the same akw directory?  Try the full path names then.  And make sure the cronjob user has permission for them.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your cron to run as www-data. Since you sending mail works from www-data, it should work fine with cron also.

Try `sudo -u www-data php index.php` in your cron. Replace index.php with the script you are trying to run.

PS: This is actually a hack. You need to play around with file permissions and come up with a robust solution.