# HTML contact form with attachment

Tags: html, forms, contacts

I am new to this and drowning, I have been searching for a few days now to try find the answer. I have made a website for a friend and in the contact us section I would like to add an attachment so when the users send the reply they can attach the completed PDF document that they downloaded from the website.

Below is the HTML code and the PHP I am using.

Please could you advise how I could use PHP to add the attachment to the mail and send it.

Thank you very much in advance

Kind regards

Jeryd

```js
<?php

// configure
$from = 'enquires@littlekidoaks.co.za';
$sendTo = 'justjilver5@gmail.com';
$subject = 'New message from contact form';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); // array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

// let's do the sending

try
{
    $emailText = "You have new message from contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );
    
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

```html
<section id="email">
    
        <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">

    <div class="messages"></div>

    <div class="controls">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_name">Firstname *</label>
                    <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_lastname">Lastname *</label>
                    <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your lastname *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                    <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_phone">Phone</label>
                    <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your phone">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                    <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please,leave us a message."></textarea>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type='file' name='upload'>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
    
    </section>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519588/send-php-html-mail-with-attachments or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431327/send-email-with-attachment-using-php or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064619/php-send-email-with-attachment should help. Where specifically are you stuck? You're not currently accessing `$_FILES['upload']` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance i appreciate it i read the other posts i am going to try PHP Mailer. I was stuck cause i did not understand how to use PHP to use the attachment still learning coding and when i read some of the answers it goes straight over my head so going to youtube PHP mailer and see if i can use that. Thank you for the answer appreciate it.